# Relationship between expectation of a function and function of the expectation?

Tags: probability

Given a convex function $f(x) \in R; dom f=R$ and $x \sim \mathcal{N}(x|m,\sigma)$. Can we find an upper bound of
$$ |E_{x }f(x)-f(m)
 |$$.

I think the upper bound should depends on the second derivative of $f(x)$, but I do not have a good way to bound this term.

Comment: Stein chacterization of $\mathscr N(x,m,\sigma)$? $E[(X-m)f(X)]={\sigma}^2E[f'(X)]$ for a broad range of functions. http://www.ims.nus.edu.sg/Programs/stein09/files/A%20Gentle%20Introduction%201.pdf